# Migration steps from SharePoint 2010 on-premises to SharePoint 2013 Azure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, azure

I'm looking for migration steps from SharePoint 2010 on-premises to SharePoint 2013 in Azure as I couldn't find anything myself anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same like any other migration / upgrade from one environment to other environment.

- Set up you Azure( create the resource group, VHD, Servers etc)
- Install the SharePoint in azure
- Configure your IP
- Move the database to Azure
- Attach to the SharePoint.
- test it

here are couple of reference to check:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bad2acb2-0eda-4947-86f8-9325e7f21a0c/move-sharepoint-onpremise-to-azure?forum=sharepointgeneral to

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_cloud_pilot/2012/06/25/moving-my-on-premises-servers-to-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-virtual-machines/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/niallsblog/2014/03/10/deploying-sharepoint-2013-on-azure/

Comment: many thanks for your response,I understand all the points listed down by you except "Configure your IP".Can you kindly explain a little more on that?

Comment: check this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_cloud_pilot/2012/06/25/moving-my-on-premises-servers-to-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-virtual-machines/